# Java - Scanner.nextLine() skipping even when accounting for new line

Tags: java, file-io

I'm trying to read from a file line by line that is tab delimited. Here's an example of a file:

```
state   0   start
state   5   accept
transition  0   0   1   x   R
transition  1   0   0   x   R
```

I create a `Scanner` object for the file and set the delimiter to `\t`. I loop through the file as long as there is a next line. I want to check whether a line begins with `state` or `transition` and then get the following information. In the case of lines that begin with `state`, I use `nextInt()` and then `next()` to obtain `0` and `start` respectively. The issue then arises of going to the next line and repeating the process. I use `nextLine()` and that's where things get ugly.

I'm aware that `nextLine()` does not consume the newline character, so I thought to use it twice and it creates more of an issue it seems.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
sc.useDelimiter("\t");

while(sc.hasNextLine())
{
    if(sc.next().equals("state") == true)
    {
        int stateNumber = sc.nextInt();
        String state = sc.next();
        sc.nextLine();
    }
    sc.nextLine();
}
```

That seems to be the relveant code that is creating issues.

Am I misunderstanding how `next()` works or am i missing something else entirely?

Comment: What do you actually intend to do with the information assuming you want to read it?

Comment: I'm taking that information and using it to construct a custom object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option here would be to simply read in each entire line in one go, and then split by a delimeter (tab) to get the individual components:

```
which (sc.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = sc.nextLine();
    String[] parts = line.split("\\t");

    if (parts[0].equals("state")) {
        // construct custom object here
    }
}
```

If you want to stick with your original approach then use this:

```
while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
    if (sc.next().equals("state")) {
        int stateNumber = sc.nextInt();
        String state = sc.next();
    }

    // consume the entire remaining line, line break included
    sc.nextLine();
}
```

For those lines containing `"state"` you were making two calls to `nextLine()`, which would result in an entire line being lost.

Comment: I did think about that, but doesn't that essentially defeat the purpose of  `Scanner`? Why use it over `FileInputStream` and do the same?